# SQL Server 2005: Determine datatype of variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is it possible to determine the type of a local variable at runtime in TSQL?

For example, say I wanted to do something along these lines:

```
IF ( @value IS INTEGER )
```

Or

```
IF ( TYPEOF(@value) = <whatever> )
```

Does anyone know of any way to accomplish this?

EDIT: This is not for a specific task, this is more of a general knowledge question. I do appreciate answers that indicate that the type should be known since it is declared within the same batch, I am curious as to whether the type can be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

run this

```
declare @d int

select @d = 500

if cast(sql_variant_property(@d,'BaseType') as varchar(20))  = 'int'
print 'yes'
else
print 'no'
```

Comment: Note: In my version of SQL Server, I just get an error running sql_variant_property() on a variable instead of a column.

Answer (score 0):

using SQL 2019 , below code still working

```
DECLARE @MyVar int;SET @MyVar = 99;
DECLARE @MyVarDataType varchar(50);

SET @MyVarDataType  = cast(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@MyVar,'BaseType') AS varchar);

PRINT @MyVarDataType
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so - BUT it is a local variable so are declaring it in the same procedure so you would know the type anyways - or am I missing something?

Comment: With the approach @SQLMenace outlined above you can find out return types for some built-in functions.  
Please see this [post](http://climenco.blogspot.com/2014/04/t-sql-coalesce-returns-int.html) for a quick example.

Comment: You'd think that, but at least one SaaS product lets you use SQL scripts but automatically declares all variables as nvarchar. I'm trying to find the exact size.