# Type of SQL expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, types

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [SQL Server check resultant data type of expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008217/sql-server-check-resultant-data-type-of-expression)
>   [SQL Server 2005: Determine datatype of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447944/sql-server-2005-determine-datatype-of-variable)

Is there a standard (SQL2008) way of determining the type of an expression?

For example, in Postgres 8.0, is there a function "TYPE_OF"

```
select TYPE_OF(COUNT(*));
```

This might return BIGINT.

I also hope it works in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008217/sql-server-check-resultant-data-type-of-expression

Comment: There's always `information_schema.columns` if you want the type of actual columns.

Comment: I think this is it: [SQL Server 2005: Determine datatype of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447944/sql-server-2005-determine-datatype-of-variable) — actually, this works for variables, but probably not for expressions. Out of curiosity, may I what ask you need this for?

Comment: SELECT 
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(count(*), 'BaseType')

Comment: @Tomalak: I am trying to convert a Java application that currently uses to Postgres 8.0 to SQL Server 2008. I need to check the types of some the Postgres query expressions to add the appropriate _CAST_ calls. Specifically, I was trying to determine the result type of a _COUNT_ call in Postgres (BIGINT).