# Why does ISNULL(NULL, NULL) return int datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on Return Types section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `ISNULL()`:

> Returns the same type as *check_expression*. If a literal `NULL` is provided as *check_expression*, returns the datatype of the *replacement_value*. **If a literal `NULL` is provided as *check_expression* and no *replacement_value* is provided, returns an `int`.**

Why does `ISNULL()` return an `int` in this case?

Comment: The documentation you have linked to is for `COALESCE`, not `ISNULL`. `COALESCE` uses data type precedence, as it is an abbreviated `CASE` expression. What are you actually asking about here? What statements confuse you? (Show examples in your question.) Why would you pass a literal `NULL` to `ISNULL` anyway?

Comment: What part of "how" do you want explained? As your quotation from the documentation states it does return an `int` under specific circumstances.

Comment: I want to know the specific circumstances

Comment: What part of the documentation you quoted is unclear then? It's quite specific.

Comment: @Larnu If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL(NULL, NULL)`

Comment: SELECT ISNULL(NULL, NULL) why is it considered as int in default ?

Comment: Because that's what the documentation says. It's documented behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps you will find enlightenment here: [Does NULL have a data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647580/does-null-have-a-data-type). Then again, perhaps not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does `SELECT ISNULL(NULL, NULL)` return a column of type `INT`

A literal `NULL` without any other context is generally just treated as an `int` in SQL Server. So this is consistent with "returns the same type as `check_expression`".

You can also see this if you do `SELECT NULL AS Col INTO SomeTable` and look at the column datatype created.

Or again can see it in this silly recursive CTE example

```
WITH R(C) AS
(
SELECT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.0 FROM R WHERE 1 = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM R
```

Which returns

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Types don't match between the
>   anchor and the recursive part in column "C" of recursive query "R".

But works fine with `0.0` replaced with `0` so the column in the recursive part is `int` rather than `decimal`.

> Why does it behave like this?

That's just what SQL Server decided to go with way back when. I doubt they would change the behaviour for backwards compatibility reasons even though it is a bit arbitrary and [probably not consistent with the SQL Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Data_typing_of_Null_and_Unknown)

The somewhat arbitrary nature of all this is also shown up by

```
SELECT NULLIF(NULL, NULL)
```

You might expect this to behave in the same way and return an `INT` but instead you get an error

> The type of the first argument to NULLIF cannot be the NULL constant
>   because the type of the first argument has to be known.

And `COALESCE(NULL,NULL)` returns

> At least one of the arguments to COALESCE must be an expression that
>   is not the NULL constant.